# Hosting with Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, hosting, web-hosting, domain-name

Can someone please direct me to a tutorial or explain the process of hosting (if possible) with Windows Azure? I have my own domain name and I would like to know how I can host my website with windows azure. It gives you the option of creating and publishing a `xxx.azurewebsites.net` but I would like to use my own personal domain.

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=azure+website+custom+domain

Answer (score 1):

Read [Azure Websites and Apps](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/).  Then you can review [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/).